# How to have Visual Studio Designer snap "bounding items" (Forms, GroupBox, Panel, etc) to controls within them?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

In Netbeans there is a nice feature where I can place all of the control I want onto a form that is larger than it will be. Then once I am done placing them I can drag the edges of the form "in" and they will snap in place based on the controls/forms padding.

In Visual Studio there is the same kind of feature but it only works when placing a control and not when resizing some sort of bounding item/control. For instance below I have a group box with a button on the very bottom.

[image]

On the right you can see the snapping feature for the button snapping to the edge of the bounding box. Though, on the left when I go to drag the bounding box toward the button it does not snap. Thus the bottom and right sides of my bounding boxes do not have the same padding distance as the top and left.

Is there a way to turn this feature on in MVS 2013? I cannot seem to find it or if it is possible.

Comment: I believe you are looking for the "anchor" property in the properties of the control?

Comment: I think it's more about using webforms and or WPF...